# Set admin role for an LDAP user in Hyperledger Fabric CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have a Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain using V1.4, I am connected through LDAP to my organization's Active Directory and I want to be able to change the roles of my users from my AD.

Basically I need two roles: user and admin, a user can run contracts and an admin can install and upgrade contracts.

So what I'm trying to do its to add a converter in my ldap configuration on fabric-ca-server-config.yaml and a map that changes my "memberOf" AD property to hf.Registrar.Roles like this:

```
ldap:
  url: ldap://CN=USER,DC=ORG1,DC=com:password@ldapserver:389/DC=ORG1,DC=com
  userfilter: (userPrincipalName=%s)
  attribute:
      names: ['userPrincipalName','memberOf']
      converters:
        - name: hf.Revoker
          value: attr("userPrincipalName") =~ "revoker*"
        - name: hf.Registrar.Roles
          value: map(attr("memberOf"),"roles")           
      maps:
        roles:
            - name: CN=BC-CLIENT,DC=ORG1,DC=com
              value: client
            - name: CN=BC-USER,DC=ORG1,DC=com
              value: user
            - name: CN=BC-ADMIN,DC=ORG1,DC=com
              value: admin
            - name: CN=BC-PEER,DC=ORG1,DC=com
              value: peer
            - name: CN=BC-ORDERER,DC=ORG1,DC=com
              value: orderer
```

So far, so good, I'm able to enroll a user using nodejs like this:

```
const ca = new FabricCAServices(caInfo.url, { trustedRoots: caTLSCACerts, verify: false }, caInfo.caName);

const enrollment = await ca.enroll({
    enrollmentID: adminId,
    enrollmentSecret: adminSecret,
});
const identity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity('Org1MSP', enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());
await wallet.import(adminId, identity);
```

With this user I can query and invoke contracts but when I try to install a contract I get the following error:

```
install proposal was bad Error: access denied for [install]: Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [The identity is not an admin under this MSP [Org1MSP]: The identity does not contain OU [ADMIN], MSP: [Org1MSP]],Error: access denied for [install]: Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [The identity is not an admin under this MSP [Org1MSP]: The identity does not contain OU [ADMIN], MSP: [Org1MSP]]
```

I can see that the mapping its working well in the CA logs, but then I guess hf.Registrar.Roles its not the property that I need.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I added an OU property to the converters like this:

```
ldap:
  attribute:
      converters:
        - name: OU
          value: map(attr("memberOf"),"roles")
```

I can see that the conversion its getting done in the CA.

```
Evaluating expression for attribute 'OU' from LDAP user 'user@company.com'
Values for LDAP attribute 'memberOf' are '[CN=BC-CLIENT,DC=ORG1,DC=com CN=BC-USER,DC=ORG1,DC=com CN=BC-ADMIN,DC=ORG1,DC=com]'
Evaluated expression for attribute 'OU'; parms: map[CN=USER,DC=ORG1,DC=com affiliation:[]]; result: client,admin,user
```

But I'm still getting the same error, so can't I map ldap attributes to the certificate?

Also here are my NodeOUs

```
NodeOUs:
  Enable: true
  ClientOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: client
  PeerOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: peer
  AdminOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: admin
  OrdererOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: orderer
```

Thanks

**SUMMARY**

Thanks to Yacov help I found out that the certificate created from LDAP always gets the client OU, and you can't change it, but it also has the OUs from the user from LDAP so you could change the NodeOUs values and map them to your organization's OU, for me that wont work as I can only change the memberOf of my users not the OUs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate needs to have the OU that defines the admin. Look at the [config.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/sampleconfig/msp/config.yaml) in your MSP folder (in the peer - MSPCONFIGPATH) and see what OU defines the administrator.

You can also try to put the certificate that you use in the `admincerts` folder of the MSP of the peer, it should also make it an admin.

Comment: Hi Jacov, so, is not possible to map the ous to the ldap attributes? Do I need to define the admin property from the creation of the certificate? I would like to be able to remove this permissions from the LDAP that wont work then? Tks

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: I want to be able to get the OUs values from my Active Directory so I can easily add and revoke the install capability for a user

Comment: You can use any OU name you want,you just need to define them accordingly in the config.yaml of the MSP config that I put in the answer

Comment: but setting the OU name in the converter doesn't work, I think the converter only maps to the certificate attributes, do I need to set it in the csr? in the enrollement request like this? ca.enroll({csr: 'OU=admin',enrollmentID: adminId,enrollmentSecret: adminSecret,}); or how can I set the OU from my ldap? the OU its being converted to admin but its not working

Comment: in the CSR, specify the OU you want as the admin OU